# Private subnets options in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I started to mess around with aws a couple days ago and I have a question about VPCs.
I'm considering two options to make "private" a subnet and I want to know your opinion:

**OPTION 1:**

A subnet with an ig attached (a public subnet really) with an ACL to only allow traffic from the VPC.
**Pros:** cheaper!
**Cons:** public ip for each instance (is this a real problem?), different public Ip for each instance (a kind of messy stuff for ip's whitelists)

**OPTION 2:**
A subnet without an ig attached using a Nat gateway.
**Pros:** more secure?, same public Ip for each instance.
**Cons:** more expensive.

I consider the Option 2 the best technical solution, only a bit more expensive. But, do you consider the option 1 a bad practice? Has more pitfalls that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Why is Option2 expensive? because of NAT?

Comment: Yes! However I'm interested about the pitfalls of version 1 even if has the same cost of option 2.

Comment: Option 3, use a NAT Instance, not a NAT Gateway.  A t2.nano or t2.micro will usually suffice, for $5 to $10/mo.

Comment: Yes, is actually a third option but I've discarded it in favor of the high resilience and scalability of the nat gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your requirements are:

- Run some Amazon EC2 instances
- Keep them "private" from the Internet (no direct access from the Internet to the instances)
- Allow the instances to access the Internet (eg to download updates, or to communicate with AWS API endpoints)

Your **Option 1** is a public subnet, made private by modifying the Network ACLs to allow traffic only within the subnet. You are giving public IP addresses to the instances, presumably so they can access the Internet. **This will not work.** The Network ACLs that limit access to the VPC will also block traffic from the instances to the Internet.

Your **Option 2** is a private subnet, with instances accessing the Internet via a NAT gateway. There is **no need to assign public IP addresses** to these instances, since they are in a private subnet. Yes, this will work but, as you note, there is the extra expense of the NAT Gateway (or a NAT instance).

An alternative is to **use a Public Subnet with Security Groups**:

- Use a **public subnet and give instances auto-assigned public IP addresses**. This will allow them to access the Internet. (Note: This is different to an *Elastic IP Address*, which is limited to 5 per region per AWS account.)
- Use a **Security Group** on each instance to block Inbound access. The instances will still be able to initiate **outbound access** to the Internet (and responses will come back because Security Groups are *stateful*)

See documentation: [Amazon EC2 Security Groups for Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Of course, since the instances now block inbound traffic, you will need a way to connect to them. This is typically done by launching a **Bastion Server** (Jump Box) in your public subnet. You can connect to the Bastion Server via public IP address, then connect to the private servers via their private IP address. To allow this, configure the Security Group on the private instances to **permit inbound traffic from the IP range of the VPC, or from the Security Group associated with the Bastion Server**.